# d3 bar chart exit not quite working

Tags: d3.js

i have a fiddle of a bar that I am working on.  I needed it to update dynamically. the problem I am having is the x axis exit and call for when the bar is re drawn. the title on the x-axis is not removed when an array item is removed.

```
   bars.exit()
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .attr("width", 0)
   .remove();


  d3.transition(svg).select(".x.axis")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

[my bar](https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/ka41pmdu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are selecting by class, it's a good idea **setting** the class when drawing the axis:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")//set the class here
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

Here is your updated fiddle with that change: https://jsfiddle.net/3mkd3njj/

Comment: its so funny because I used your code to figure out as much as i did...

Comment: you have some update, enter  exit example on stack overflow

Comment: Oh, in the Docs? Yes. You can see that I'm setting the class there too.

Comment: Well, i found that and i updated but did not save the fiddle before i pasted the link here. my bad.  but even now looking at the updated fiddle the chart does not seem to take the salesPerson off the axis. probably a new question though...